# get value of each class of span and put string to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of values in a spans called 'tag-label'.  I wish to add the value of each of these spans and insert them in a input field separated by commas.

I have set up a JSFiddle to show it. http://jsfiddle.net/stefanselby/7wrg611k/

My HTML:

```
<label for="TagsHolder">Keywords</label>
<ul>
   <li><span class="tag-label">test 1</span></li>
   <li><span class="tag-label">test 2</span></li>
   <li><span class="tag-label">test 3</span></li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="TagsHolder" name="TagsHolder" value="" />
<button id="btn">Update</button>
<p></p>
<p>This is what I require</p>
<input type="text" id="TagsHolder2" name="TagsHolder2" value="test 1,test 2,test 3" />
```

My Javascript (where I am stuck):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
       $.each($('.tag-label'), function (index, value) {
           $("#TagsHolder").val(index);
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.map` to get an array, then join on a `,`

```
var values = $(".tag-label").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(",");

$("#TagsHolder").val(values);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7wrg611k/3/

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with your approach.

`index` is the array index of the current element, not it's text.

Your loop will replace the value each pass, so only the last value will be seen since each previous value set will be replaced

Your best bet is to create an array and join that array:

```
 $("#btn4").click(function () {
    var values = $('.tag-label').map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join();
    $("#TagsHolder").val(values);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7wrg611k/1/)**</kbd>